# console view not displaying in eclipse when debug perspective is selected

Tags: eclipse, ide, console, window, eclipse-kepler

Eclipse IDE console view is not displaying in Debug perspective is selected.
If I select Console view from `Window -> Show View -> Console` then there is no `Console View` is displayed it is hiding. How to display Console view in Eclipse IDE when Debug perspective is selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Try resetting debug perspective first. Click `Windows > Reset perspective..` then open console view.

Comment: Can you supply more info about the state of the UI at the point where you try to show the view ? A screen cap would be great if possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unfortunately press some shortcut key of `eclipse kepler` suddenly eclipse console window is closed.

Problem is solved after **open** eclipse **new window** from ***Window Menu*** `Window -> New Window` and closed previously opened window.